# How to upload a single variable to Azure table storage c#

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I am trying to upload a single variable (var usertext) into Azure table storage, How do I go about doing this?

I have already been able to create my table storage through Azure, but am struggling to work out how I send data to be stored within the table.

Any help or insight into this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet?toc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Ftables%2FTOC.json&bc=%2Fen-us%2Fazure%2Fbread%2Ftoc.json) for more details about table storage operation.

The detailed step is as below:

1.Create a console application in your visual studio.

2.Add NuGet package [WindowsAzure.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage) and [windowsAzure.ConfigurationManager](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ConfigurationManager/) to your solution.

3.In the `app.config`, add the following:

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="StorageConnectionString"value="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=account-name;AccountKey=account-key" />
</appSettings>
```

4.Code as below:

```
    using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;

    using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Table;

    using Microsoft.Azure;
```

Create a particular class with some field that will be inherited from TableEntity, like below.

```
    public class CustomerEntity : TableEntity
    {
        public CustomerEntity(string lastName, string firstName)
        {
            this.PartitionKey = lastName;
            this.RowKey = firstName;
        }

        public CustomerEntity() { } // the parameter-less constructor must be provided

        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
   }
```

Then in the Main() method, you can insert your data to table storage.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Parse the connection string and return a reference to the storage account.
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

            // Create the table client.
            CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

            // Retrieve a reference to the table.
            CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("Mytable");

            // Create the table if it doesn't exist.
            table.CreateIfNotExists();

            // Create a new customer entity.
            CustomerEntity customer1 = new CustomerEntity("Harp", "Walter");
            customer1.Email = "Walter@contoso.com";
            customer1.PhoneNumber = "425-555-0101";

            // Create the TableOperation object that inserts the customer entity.
            TableOperation insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(customer1);

            // Execute the insert operation.
            table.Execute(insertOperation);
        }
     }
```

Comment: Followed steps but cannot seem to see the users text data within the table storage

Comment: Please make sure the connection string is correct in app.config. Then could you please post your code here? so that I can see what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the following steps:

1. Add NuGet package `"WindowsAzure.Storage"` to your solution
2. Create a particular class with some field that will be inherited from `TableEntity`
3. Assing your `usertext` into field iside you new class
4. Create TableOperation: `TableOperation tableOperation = TableOperation.Insert(entity);`
5. Execute TableOperation: `TableResult tableResult = await cloudTable.ExecuteAsync(tableOperation);`

Comment: Thanks for you response! Could you explain step 3, 4, and 5 a bit more as I'm slightly stuck